# "Error: Unable to initialize main class, Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [LString"

Tags: java, eclipse

After running the code I am getting this problem, "Error: Unable to initialize main class lab5_0.Total
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [LString;" , I have no idea what is wrong with the settings
[image]

Comment: What does it say in the Problems view? The `package` line is showing an error

Comment: Java isn't able to find the .class file for your source file.  It may have been deleted and needs to be rebuilt.  You should also check your Project Classpath settings and look for unresolved dependencies.  Eclipse is halting the build process for a particular reason.  The Problems view will be specific.

Comment: It's not finding `String[].class`, which suggests that the installation is pretty borked.

Comment: We need to know more about this project. Is this a maven project (not likely in this case)?  Show the package explorer view of your project.

Comment: I didn't really get the problem, but it has been solved! I uninstalled everything and installed it again.

Comment: Also, Thank you everyone for replying to me. I was super busy at that time and forgot later, but then I've just remembered and wanted to post the solution if it helps someone!